# Eliminar menú de controles de ventana de visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo eliminar ese menu negro de una ventana de visual studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para Visual Studio en ingles:

```
Tools –> Options –> Debugging –> General –> Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML
```

Para Visual Studio en español:

```
Herramientas -> Opciones -> Depuración -> General -> Habilitar las herramientas de interfaz de usuario para XAML
```